# Require.js Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I just started learning [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/)

the **file system** is like :

[image]

This is my **index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/require/require.min.js" data-main="lib/main"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <span id="content"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, this I knows that the **1st** file that loaded on to the DOM is require.js then after that it loads **lib/main.js**

Now the **main.js** is

```
require(['jquery'],function($){
     //this works since both **main.js** and **jquery.js** are in same folder
     $("#content").html("jquery am  loaded");
});
```

[image]
Now here is the problem if I keep **jquery.js** in the same folder as that in main.js the code works fine, but if I change the path to jquery/jquery.js and change the main.js as

```
require(['jquery/jquery'],function($){
     //this thing shows 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function'
     $("#content").html("jquery am  loaded");
});
```

I understood the problem is that it is not loading the **jquery.js** if it is inside any other folder other that ***main.js*** is, but why, please shed some light and how that can be achieved.

Answer (score 7):

To use RequireJS and jQuery, you should either use the combined RequireJS/jQuery file, available at:

http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

Or use a `path`.

http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-paths

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery": 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1'
    }
});

require(["jquery"], function ($) {
    console.log($.fn.jquery);
});
```

Comment: Recently I used your code and saw that the jquery file is loading in **Network Inspector** but I am still confused why the **require.js** is not pushing the parameter in **$** of the callback.

Comment: Not pushing the $ parameter in which callback?

Comment: require(['jquery/jquery'],function($){
     //here $ is the parameter which is pushed or placed with the content of the jquery, right?
     $("#content").html("jquery am  loaded");
});

Comment: What about using `./jquery/jquery` instead (**if** `jquery/jquery` is relative to `main.js`). Note that is not the correct way.